# Why doesn’t it burn?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

In this [video by Chatzida - 11 Fascinating Chemistry Experiments (Compilation)](https://youtu.be/8vyboVwyzfU?t=229) there’s an experiment where they light a bank note on fire, but it doesn’t burn. Why doesn’t it burn?

Answer (score 3):

In order for a combustible substance to ignite, it must first attain a certain temperature called the 'autoignition point', which is the minimum temperature that the substance requires to begin combustion. In this case, the banknote didn't 'burn' because the water present absorbs the majority of the energy given off by the combustion of ethanol, which keeps the temperature of the banknote below its ignition point. As per the explanation given by the video, "water protects the paper by absorbing the energy of alcohol combustion". Water is particularly good at absorbing energy with a minimum increase in temperature due to its hydrogen bonding, which is the attractive forces between the polar ends of water molecules.

Comment: The solvent was ignited with a lighter so it isn't the "autoignition point" but rather the "ignition point".